# Is there a way to pin the Actions column in material-react-table?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, material-react-table

I want to pin the actions column in a material-react-table on the right by default. is there any way to achieve this?

I tried using the following, but it did not return the desired result.
`initialState={{ columnPinning: { right: ["RowActions"] }, }}`

Comment: initialState={ columnPinning: { right: ['mrt-row-actions'], //pin built-in row actions display column to right by default },}

Comment: it worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

The default name for row actions is mrt-row-actions, you may try this:

```
initialState: {
      columnPinning: { right: ['mrt-row-actions'] },
},
```